# Job failed on Google Cloud ML Engine

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml

I wanted to do a classification model using Google ML Engine. I took [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/how-to-classify-images-with-tensorflow-using-google-cloud-machine-learning-and-cloud-dataflow) as reference and successfully followed this post till preprocessing step.
After executing the training command, I'm getting the following error message:

```
The replica master 0 exited with a non-zero status of 1. Traceback (most recent call last): [...] 
File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 436, in run dispatch(args, model, cluster, task) 
File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 477, in dispatch Trainer(args, model, cluster, task).run_training() 
File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 241, in run_training self.eval(session) 
File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 283, in eval ` self.model.format_metric_values(self.evaluator.evaluate())) 
File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/task.py", line 57, in evaluate self.eval_batch_size)
File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/model.py", line 300, in build_eval_graph return self.build_graph(data_paths, batch_size, GraphMod.EVALUATE)
File "/root/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/trainer/model.py", line 224, in build_graph tensors.examples = tf.placeholder(tf.string, name='input', shape=(None,)) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1502, in placeholder name=name) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 2149, in _placeholder name=name)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 763, in apply_op op_def=op_def) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2327, in create_op original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def) 
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1226, in __init__ self._traceback = _extract_stack() 
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'input' with dtype string 
[[Node: input = Placeholder[dtype=DT_STRING, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"]()]]
```

Kindly help me out with this..

Comment: Hi New_coder, can you add the following: `pip freeze` and the command you are running when launching the preprocess.py. Based on the error it may be related to  an issue in the parameters passed for input.

Comment: Please make sure you are defining "input_path" and "input_dict" correctly. Error seems to be pointing there. DICT_FILE=gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/dict.txt and --input_path "gs://cloud-ml-data/img/flower_photos/eval_set.csv"

Comment: I have my own dict file and input path. While executing the training command, I used my own files and path. @spicyramen

Comment: Can you share some sample data for both files? To make sure is the right format.